# dual cycle data generation

Tags: optimization, python

I want to generate 2x6 dataframe which represents a rack to optimizing a dual cycle in optimizing warehouse.Half of this dataframe are filled with storage items and the other half is with retrieval items. I want to do is random chosing half of these 12 items and say that they are storage and others are retrieval. How can I randomly choose?

I tried random.sample but this chooses random columns.Actually I want to choose random items individually.

Answer (score 1):

Assign each of the 12 items a number drawn from the U[0,1] distribution. The six items with the lowest uniform values are "storage", the six with the highest values are "retrieval".